# Would a rational voter with a lower IQ vote differently than one with a higher IQ?

Tags: united-states, voting, inequality

I recently came across the claim that American liberals do, on average, score higher on IQ tests than American conservatives. Being a conservative I spent some time considering how I should feel about this.

- [Do smart people tend to be more liberal? Yes, but it doesn’t mean all conservatives are stupid](https://theconversation.com/do-smart-people-tend-to-be-more-liberal-yes-but-it-doesnt-mean-all-conservatives-are-stupid-57713)
- [Why Liberals Are More Intelligent Than Conservatives](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-scientific-fundamentalist/201003/why-liberals-are-more-intelligent-conservatives)

One thing I was not sure about is whether it is possible that the policies that benefit the less intelligent can be genuinely different from those that benefit the more intelligent. Is it possible that a rational agent with lower IQ will, everything else being equal, vote differently from a rational agent with higher IQ? I guess they might vote differently if one party proposes to execute the less intelligent but in a less eugenicist context is there still a difference?

Comment: I feel this post includes a very interesting topic (existing answer show how). I have edited the title to be somewhat on-topic, but I am not happy with the content.

Comment: It's hard to imagine why that would be impossible. Suppose people with lower IQ tend to have certain jobs or live in certain areas. Then they'd be more likely to vote for politicians that promise to help those jobs or those areas, right?

Comment: Education is a more accurate predictor of political leanings than IQ. Often, above-average IQ individuals can make a system work for them that less smart people struggle to find security and stability in; tradespeople for example, and they skew conservative as a result of finding gov resources personally unneeded. Those with a 4-year degree are often aware of the context behind social problems, which gives them a different approach to cost/benefit analysis than other thinkers, who over-simplify into more personal outcomes; eg. gov drug rehab costs me money, it doesn't reduce crime against me.

Comment: The premise relies on IQ -- the ability to score well on certain standardized tests -- being a useful metric for decision-making, let alone one distinct from other factors.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "rational voter" or "rational voting". At best your question is opinion-based, in actuality it is non-sensical.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to imagine any specific policy which would directly target people with low IQ. The only ones I could think of are:

- Eugenics, as mentioned in the question, but that would be highly unethical
- Hiring criteria in the public sector (as many standardized hiring tests are often just IQ tests, this is actually one of the few areas of life where IQ scores actually results in direct discrimination)

Other than that, IQ does correlate with a lot of demographic factors, and political policies often have very different effects on people based on their demographic factors. The correlation relationship looks like this:

```
policy effect -> demographics <-> IQ
```

Policy affect demographics and demographics correlate with IQ. But there is no direct connection between policy effects and IQ. The connection is indirect through demography membership. So a perfectly rational agent would see that their membership of various demographic groups is a far better predictor for which representatives will benefit them than using their IQ as a proxy.

---

Example:

Let's assume for the sake of argument that science has proven beyond reasonable doubt that owners of red cars have a higher median IQ than owners of blue cars.

Charlie runs for president and says "red cars should pay higher toll fees than blue cars".

Bob owns a red car, but he happens to be a statistical anomaly. His IQ is actually below average.

Should Bob vote for Charlie?

No, because Charlies policies hurt Bob (as a member of the red car owner demographic) directly. People with low IQ as a general demographic would on average perhaps benefit from Charlie being president, because there are more blue car owners among them than red car owners. But that has no effect on Bob personally, because he as one of the few low IQ red car owners would be the exception.

By the way, this logic can be transferred to a lot of other demographic relations which actually exist in real life and do have real world political implications. Like for example:

```
policy effect -> income group <-> ethnicity

policy effect -> leisure activity <-> gender

policy effect -> food preference <-> religion
```

Just because a policy disproportionally affects people of your demographic (positively or negatively) does not mean they affect you personally in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a frame challenge answer. In my opinion question is invalid because it mixes incompatible assumptions.**

The very notion of "rational voter" by definition precludes the very possibility of diverging IQ. Within political and economical sciences "[rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_agent)" assumes having perfect knowledge of situation and being able to perfectly make optimal choice.

> In economics, game theory, decision theory, and artificial intelligence, a rational agent is an agent that has clear preferences, models uncertainty via expected values of variables or functions of variables, and always chooses to perform the action with the optimal expected outcome for itself from among all feasible actions. A rational agent can be anything that makes decisions, typically a person, firm, machine, or software.

One of possible definitions of [intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence) is:

> A very general mental capability that, among other things, involves the ability to reason, plan, solve problems, think abstractly, comprehend complex ideas, learn quickly and learn from experience.

Most if not all definitions of intelligence consider ability to reason, make mental calculations and model reality to be within scope of intelligence. This would be analogous to "rational agent's" ability to make choice, with crucial difference being that unlike real humans, "rational agent" always makes optimal choice.

As such, **rational voter by definition has infinite knowledge and infinite intelligence**.

Thus any attempt at modelling differing IQ, knowledge or education automatically models voter who is not rational, hence my claim that this question is invalid due to incompatible assumptions.

Note that definition from wiki mentions that agent "has clear preferences", however within politics, preferences would come from person's economic standing, ethnicity, family situation, health, ethics and other factors which within those definitions are external elements, entirely outside of rationality.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, it is useful to clarify what we are *actually* talking about *before* we start talking about it. With that point in mind...

IQ tests measure the ability to solve certain kinds of abstract puzzles. They were originally popularized by the military and heavy industry — both of which had influxes of under-educated workers/soldiers — to separate out those who had an aptitude for working with increasingly complex devices. This is simple pragmatics: anyone can be taught run a machine by rote, but people who have a knack for puzzling out how the machine *works* will be more effective and less prone to error than those who don't have that knack. Of course, the scores on this measure distribute along a bell curve, meaning that there are some people who are dismally poor at solving these kinds of puzzles and some who excel at it, but it's worth noting that IQ tests are *standardized*, meaning that the current tested average is defined to be 100, and the current tested standard deviation is is defined to be 15. There is evidence to show that the population average has been increasing over time: e.g., people scoring the mean score of 100 in the 1940s would probably have scored a standard deviation or so below the current mean (85±). That effect is not well understood, but probably has to do with the increasing pressure of social and technological advances, which demand that people become more sophisticated puzzlers at earlier ages.

Disentangling rational actor theory from puzzle-solving is problematic. Rational actor theory has always tended to imagine people as sophisticated puzzle-solvers confronted with a series of more or less independent puzzles. In fact, the critiques of rational actor theory are the same critiques leveled against IQ tests:

- No sensitivity to cultural contexts or differences
- Exclusion of social norms or moral imperatives as intellectual factors
- No facility for modeling systemic or path-dependent contexts
- A broad tendency to discount sympathy, empathy, common sense, authenticity, overarching perspectives, or other cognitive states and abilities that do not lie within the simple, focused, puzzle-solving mode

Rational actor theory, in a nutshell, is a field which models the world as though everyone scores high on IQ tests, and then puzzles over what that might mean for the real world. A rational actor (within rational actor theory) is by definition high-IQ; the idea of a low-IQ rational actor literally makes no sense within that worldview.

Now let me get to actually answering the question...

People who score high on IQ tests — puzzle-solvers — look at the political/social world and see it as a set of puzzles to be solved. This tends to draw them towards the political left, because the political left has always been the 'fix it' side of the spectrum. People who are *not* puzzle-solvers tend *not* to see the political/social world that way. They tend to get drawn towards the conservative side, if only because they are irked at all the 'fix it' noise puzzle-solvers are making. This creates an imbalance in IQ scores between the orientations, without really creating an imbalance in *intelligence*. I'd argue, in fact (following [Benedetto Croce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedetto_Croce)), that the real difference between Liberals and Conservatives is a matter of **aesthetics**: Liberals imagine a beautiful world of freedom and equality that must be created; Conservatives see a beautiful world of tradition, honor, and community that must *not* be destroyed; each side uses reason in different modes to argue its position.

The question of policy is a rat's nest, and we cannot simply or easily talk about policies aimed at high-IQ or low-IQ people. Policy is often written in such a way that *appears* to be one thing but is *implemented* as another thing entirely. Puzzle-solvers will tend to try to ferret out all the details and implications, where non-puzzle solvers will tend to take things more at face value. But the first can an easily lead to paranoid conspiracy theory as deep understanding, while the second might be a wise application of common sense or a foolish indulgence of ignorance. We need to define intelligence more broadly than mere puzzle-solving capacity to make sense of this.